# SQLAlchemy sessions keep dropping after a few minutes

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am writing a Flask API that needs to communicate with many datastores, Postgres on AWS RDS being one of them. I want to avoid Flask-SQLAlchemy (trying to reduce package dependence), and given that my use case is pretty simple, I think the standard SQLAlchemy library should suffice. This is my `models.py` file:

```
class DriverPostgres:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connector = PostgresCredentials()
        self.connection_str = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(...)
        self.engine = create_engine(self.connection_str)
        self.Session = scoped_session(
            sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=self.engine))
        Base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)

    def get_user_by_email(self, email):
        session = self.Session()
        result = session.query(User).filter_by(email=email).first()
        self.Session.remove()
        return result

    def register_user(self, ...):
        user = User(...)
        session = self.Session()
        session.add(user)
        try:
            session.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            return False
        finally:
            self.Session.remove()
        return True
```

In my Flask app `server.py` file, I import `DriverPostgres` at the top of the app and instantiate `driver_postgres = DriverPostgres()`, and when handling requests I make calls like `driver_postgres.get_user_by_email()`. This logic works perfectly when the app is first loaded. I can send as many requests through as I want with no issues. However, if I wait for a few minutes and hit the app again, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/userserver.py", line 118, in login
    response = driver_postgres.check_password(email, password)
  File "/Users/usermodels.py", line 125, in check_password
    user_to_check = self.get_user_by_email(email)
  File "/Users/usermodels.py", line 154, in get_user_by_email
    result = session.query(User).filter_by(email=email).first()
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2835, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2627, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2935, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2958, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 508, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
 [SQL: ...] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

This is rather crippling. I have spent a lot of time going through SO and many tutorials, and this seems to be a standard valid pattern, so I am not sure what is going wrong. Should I not be removing the session? Should I be using the `@app.teardown_appcontext` decorator (it seems that if I just remove the sessions myself as I am doing now, I shouldn't have to)? Should I be using a connection pool instead (it seems that `QueuePool` is enabled under the hood by default anyway)? If it helps, I am using the latest version of all packages, Python 3.6.5, and Postman to send the requests to the server, which is running at `localhost:5000`. Any advice would be much appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: I had exactly the same idea as you, 'why use flask-sqlalchemy if you can just use sqlalchemy`. And then I also got a whole array of weird and hard to follow errors, and then stumbled on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343740/flask-sqlalchemy-or-sqlalchemy). So long story short, if your app is (fairly) simple, use Flask-SQLalchemy because it takes care of a lot of stuff for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the app is not that simple, and has to handle significant load. The main problem I have with Flask-SQLAlchemy is that I have _many_ data sources, and want to be as flexible as possible. Defining this as the main database in a way that differs from the other data sources is really not ideal. No other data driver is having this issue.